# Alt + Tab only toggles between two recent windows on 16.04 in MATE

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate, application-switcher

I'm using the MATE desktop environment on 16.04. The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination only toggles between the two most recently accessed windows on the same workspace. It doesn't switch at all to all other windows that are open within the same workspace. I am pressing and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing and releasing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times. Any workarounds?

Comment: Try this experiment and edit question with the results please? Place one window in a virtual workspace by itself, switch to that workspace. Are other windows accessible via alt+tab?

Comment: Just tried this, doesnt work, i.e., the other windows are not accessible via Alt+tab. BTW, I'm not sure what the intent of the experiment was.

Comment: The point is, windows not on the same workspace are inaccessible via alt+tab. Some windows managers work this way as a feature, not a bug. Now people trying to help have the field of issues narrowed down a bit.

Answer (score 4):

The default function per [Martin Wimpress](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1493408/comments/7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle Applications in CURRENT workspace.
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle Applications in ALL workspaces.

To check them run:

```
gsettings get org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows 
gsettings get org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all 
gsettings get org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all-backward
```

To Change them run a variation of the following code with your preferred settings:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows 'disabled'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all '<Alt>Tab'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all-backward '<Shift><Alt>Tab'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the default is actually the opposite of this in recent Linux Mint MATE distributions.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate and linux Mint Mate are different distributions, and while they share much different distros are very likely to have different defaults based on their goals and philosophy.